# HW : search for input string in text document

Tags: java

this is my first post so forgive me if i have posted incorrectly. I have a task that i need to complete but i cant get it to work properly. the compiler that i use is bluej. what i need to do is to use scanner to read a text file and compare a user input to the text file. if the input string compares then it should print out that ""The word is on the text file". Unfortunately i cant get this to work. My code reads the file because it prints out to the console but no comparison it s happening. please have a look at my code and give me some pointers. i have been trying to use .equals():

```
private boolean searchFromRecord(String recordName, String word) throws IOException
{
    // Please write your code after this line
    File file = new File(recordName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

        for(int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++){
            String compare = scanner.nextLine();
            IO.outputln("word#" + i + ":" + compare);
        }

        scanner.close(); 

        if (scanner.equals(word)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

this is what i get output in the console:

```
Input a word: IRON
AA 888
word#0:BULLET
word#1:1
word#2:AE 1688
word#3:CHEERS
word#4:GAMES
word#5:IRON MAN
word#6:WOLF
word#7:Testing
word#8:Wonderful
The word "IRON" is not in the record.
```

Comment: can you post up your file content?

Comment: How could a Scanner ever be equal to a String? Only a String can be equal to another String.

Comment: You need to call scanner.nextLine() just *ONCE* for each line, then *SAVE* the line to a String variable as soon as you read it.  For example: `String line= scanner.nextLine();`.  Then you need to see if :line" contains your "word".  For example: `if (line.indexOf (word) >= 0) { /* Found one! */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some problems, along with why they are problems & a suggestion on how they could be fixed:

1. **Problem:** closing a scanner within the a loop that uses it will cause an exception. **Reason:** after we go through the loop once, the scanner will be closed. when we loop through again, an error will occur since the loop uses the scanner, which means the scanner should be "open". **Possible solution:** move `scanner.close()` to after the while loop.
2. **Problem:** we shouldn't return `true` at the end of this method. **Reason:** I'm guessing that this method is supposed to return `true` if the word is found, and `false` otherwise. Now, the only way to get to this return statement is if our word doesn't exist in the recordFile; it should return `false`. **Possible solution:** return `false` at the end of the method instead.
3. **Problem:** the first line in `recordFile` will never be checked for equality with `word` **Reason:** each method call of `scanner.nextLine()` will return each line from the `recordFile` as a String once and only once. In your code, it is called once in the beginning of the while loop's body, but not used to compare with word, then after, it is used in the for loop for comparison **Possible solution:** remove the line: `System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());`.
4. **Problem:** `scanner.equals(word)` will probably always return `false`. **Reason:** `scanner` is a `Scanner`, and `word` is a `String`, they should never be equal. **Possible solution:** replace `scanner.equals(word)` with `compare.equals(word)`
5. **Problem:** `word` is not actually compared with each `compare`. **Reason:** it is outside the for loop. **Possible solution:** move the if else block into the end of the for loop's body.
6. I don't think the while loop is really needed. I strongly recommend that the while loop, is removed, but keep the body.
7. **Problem:** Moving the if else block into the for loop, and above the `scanner.close()` means that the `scanner.close()` will never be run. **Reason:** once a return statement is executed, the flow of control immediatly exits the method, and returns to where the method was invoked which makes code after return statements useless. **Possible solution:** instead of returning right away, declare some sort of boolean variable that will store the return value. have the return value be modified throughout the method, then return the variable at the very end, after `scaner.close()`

There are many many other ways to fix each of these problems other than the ones suggested here.

I hope you find this helpful! :)

---

**your code, refactored to implement the suggested solutions above:**

```
private boolean searchFromRecord(String recordName, String word) throws IOException {
    // Please write your code after this line
    Boolean wordFound = false;  // indicates if word exists in recordFile.
    File file = new File(recordName);   // file at path "recordName"
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);    // reads records from "file"

    // iterate through the recordFile, to see if "word" already exists
    // within recordFile.
    for(int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++) {

        // read the record from the file
        String compare = scanner.nextLine();
        IO.outputln("word#" + i + ":" + compare);

        // compare the record with our word
        if (compare.equals(word)){
            wordFound = true;
            break;      // bail out of loop, our work here is done
        }
    }

    // clean up, and return...
    scanner.close();
    return wordFound;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation Eric its very helpful and explains everything step by in terms i can understand. this took all the fogginess away very very very much appreciated

Comment: Compilation Test: Passed.Number of Test Case Groups Passed:1/1
The Content of Input File for Testing:
environment
environmental
environmentally_friendly
peace
peaceful
peacefully
Test Case Passed: (4/4)
Given the user input is
environmentally_friendly
The expected result is true.Your code returns true.Passed
Given the user input ispeace
The expected result is true.Your code returns true.Passed
Given the user input isThe_object_is_created.The expected result is false.Your code returns false.Passed
Given the user input isenvironmentally
The expected result is false.Your code returns false.Passed

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy that you found this useful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First, `scanner` is not a `String` and it will not equal a `String`. Second, you are dropping lines - `scanner.nextLine()` gets the next line, and you print it (but don't save it or compare it). I think you wanted something more like this,

```
// eats and tosses input.
// System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
String line = scanner.nextLine();
for(int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++){
  String compare = scanner.nextLine();
  IO.outputln("word#" + i + ": " + compare + " to line: " + line);
  if (line.contains(compare)){ // "IRON MAN" starts with "IRON", it doesn't equal IRON.
    return true;
  }
}
scanner.close();     
return false; // <-- default.
```

Comment: its still tells me in the console that the word is not in the file.Input a word: WOLF
The word "WOLF" is not in the record.

Answer (score 0):

**Another flavor** is to read the whole file into a String variable and look for specified String inside the String.

Code:

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\KICK\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects"
                + "\\SearchWordinFile\\src\\searchwordinfile\\words.txt");
        String s="";
       try(Scanner input = new Scanner(file)){
           input.useDelimiter("\\A");
            if (input.hasNext()) {
                s = input.next();
            }
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
        if(s.contains("IRON"))
            System.out.println("I found IRON");
    }
```

Output:

```
I found IRON
```

My File content

```
BULLET
1
AE 1688
CHEERS
GAMES
IRON MAN
WOLF
Testing
Wonderful
```

Comment: i just want to say thank you for the assistance. by using your code and editing it a little bit so that it points to the files and input i need it worked 100%

Comment: you are welcome. just read this to get more info so you can be ready when you want to explain to your teacher or whoever https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner.html